# Access values in nested dictionary in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am basically trying to access a value inside a dictionary that is inside another one.

```
void main() {
var results = {
  'usd' : {"first": 2, "second": 4},
  'eur' : 4.10, 
  'gbp' : 4.90, 
  };

  print(results['usd']["first"]);

}
```

The issue is I am facing that I get an error:

> Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
>
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
>   print(results['usd']["first"]);

I cannot find the explanation for it, and how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the type to `Map` like:

```
void main() {
Map results = {
  'usd' : {"first": 2, "second": 4},
  'eur' : 4.10, 
  'gbp' : 4.90, 
  };

  print(results['usd']['first'].toString());

}
```

Comment: Better Dart style is to add the types to the map as: `final results = <String, dynamic>{`

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because your `results` map has values of different types. Euro and Pound are doubles, but Dollar is a map. So the compiler can't infer a better type for `results` than `Map<String, Object>`. You need to give it some help, by telling it the type of type of the `usd` value.

```
void main() {
  var results = {
    'usd': {
      'first': 2,
      'second': 4,
    },
    'eur': 4.10,
    'gbp': 4.90,
  };

  final usd = results['usd'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(usd['first']);
}
```